# Python Image analysis

Tags: python, image

i'm kinda a Python newbie, so please do not get angry! 
I want to start a web project which consist on manipulation on a file audio based on a series of mathematical images which I have to analyse.

[image]

I have around 700 of these images. I have to extract the curve and the points on that curve and from that use the extracted function to manipulate and alter a single file audio. 
My question is: what library do you suggest?

Comment: Have you tried OpenCV or PIL? If your images have exact same dimensions, you could simply "traverse" along X axis in a specific region and decide where the black pixel lies in that X.

Comment: @TuwuhS Yes, all same size. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html#table-of-content-feature2d Do you think OpenCV can help me to achieve that?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('so9QZ.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_cropped = img[89:201, 22:214]
values = img_cropped.shape[0] - np.argmin(img_cropped.T, axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(np.arange(*values.shape), values)
plt.show()
```

The idea here is to first manually crop the region of interest (ROI) from image `img` into `img_cropped` to get the following image:

[image]

I obtained the coordinates `[89:201, 22:214]` manually using image editor (I just used mspaint).

I then transposed the cropped image using `img_cropped.T`. The reason for this is that OpenCV stores image in row-major (Y) order while we want to traverse it column-wise (X).

`np.argmin` is applied to this transposed array to find the index (Y coordinate) with the minimum value (blackest pixel). The origin of an image is on top-left so we will get an "inverted" value (higher value means lower in Y), so we subtract that from the cropped image height `img_cropped.shape[0]`.

Plotting the result:

[image]

Yes, it's not perfect, but as I said should get you started.

Comment: Yes. I was looking exactly this as my starting point! Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Glad to help! ;)